# Call printf with x87 float

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, x87

I have a simple program in x86 asm, which makes `z = x/y`. The thing is, the code should be written correctly when it comes to division, but nothing is printed. There is no output. I have no idea what's wrong, because I can't debug when the program doesn't use eax, ebx etc.

```
global main
extern printf

section .text

    main:

    finit
    fild dword[x]
    fild dword[y]
    fdiv
    fist dword[z]

    push dword[z]
    push frm
    call printf
    add esp,8

    mov ebx,0
    mov eax,1
    int 0x80


section .data
x: dd 1.2
y: dd 3.14
z: dd 0.0
frm: dd '%lf',10,0
```

Comment: Try without `mov ebx,0` + you should read about floats in x86 asm.

Comment: gdb can show the FP registers (`p $st0`, or `tui reg float`).  But your problem is not the contents of FP regs.

Comment: Aren't varargs floats promoted to doubles?

Comment: @MargaretBloom: yes.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37082784/how-to-print-a-single-precision-float-with-printf.  Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442155/printing-floats-with-printf-in-x86-nasm-32-bit for x87 `fstp qword [esp]`.  But this program isn't printing *anything*, so that's not the only bug.  Perhaps its being built as 64-bit code, where `printf` has a different calling convention?  Or else `printf` doesn't like it when you call it with the x87 stack not empty (which the ABI requires).  What do you see if you run it under `strace`?

Comment: The format string does contain a newline, so printf should print even though it exits with `sys_exit` without flushing stdio buffers.  Unless your `stdout` isn't a TTY, in which case you also have this problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38379553/using-printf-in-assembly-leads-to-an-empty-ouput.  (It would be good practice to just `ret` from `main` when you're using C library functions.)

Comment: update: `dd` means that there's a terminating `0` before the newline, see comments below.

Answer (score 2):

1) The C library - I guess you use the one from GCC - doesn't output the result of `printf` immediately. Rather, it is stored in a separate memory called cache and outputted by chance. In this case the program will be ended by `int 0x80/eax=1` faster than the cache will be flushed. You can insert a manual flush:

```
...
extern fflush
...
push 0
call fflush
add esp, 4
...
```

The best solution is to use the C `exit` function. Replace

```
mov ebx,0
mov eax,1
int 0x80
```

by

```
push 0
call exit
```

2) `printf` with format `%lf` needs a double floating point number (8 bytes = QWORD) as input. So change the code:

```
...
fstp qword[z]
...
push dword[z+4]
push dword[z]
push frm
call printf
add esp,12
...
z: dq 0.0
```

3) NASM will interpret and convert 1.2 and 3.14 as floating point number. Defined as `dd` it will be stored as single floating point number. However, `fild` expects and loads an **integer** number. Let it load as single:

```
fld dword[x]
fld dword[y]
```

The whole bunch:

```
global main
extern printf, fflush, exit

section .text

    main:

    finit
    fld dword[x]
    fld dword[y]
    fdiv
    fstp qword[z]

    push dword[z+4]
    push dword[z]
    push frm
    call printf
    add esp,12

    push 0
    call fflush
    add esp, 4

    push 0
    call exit

section .data
x: dd 1.2
y: dd 3.14
z: dq 0.0
frm: dd '%lf',10,0
```

Comment: I think you still leave the x87 stack unbalanced: you should use `fdivp`, or `fdiv dword[y]` instead of the 2nd load.  Also, `sub esp,8` / `fstp qword [esp]` would be a lot simpler.  And you don't need to call `fflush` if you `call exit` or `ret` from main.  You only need `fflush` if you call `sys_exit` manually, or similar bypassing of the normal exit cleanup.  (And BTW, shift_left was correct: using `dd '%lf', 10` was a problem: it puts a `0` terminator before the LF, otherwise `printf` would print right away when stdout is line-buffered.  It's not a cache, it's an I/O *buffer*.)

Answer (score 1):

**FILD** Load Integer

*Converts the signed-integer source operand into double extended-precision floating-point format*

3.14 & 1.2 are not integers.

- 314 / 12 = 26.1666 then shift decimal left or
- 314 / 120 = 2.61666 or
- Use DT and declare as extended precision float.

  ```
  dd     3.14                ; equates to 4048F5C3H = 1,078,523,331
  dd     1.2                 ;            3F99999Ah = 1,067,030,938
  ```

  So the result is going to be 9.8934432601532659843776712884109e-1 and FIST is going to convert that to zero

Strings are declared with DB not DD  so

```
    frm:     db      '%lf', 10, 0 will solve that problem
```

Comment: `dd` for the string merely results in extra padding (out to a dword boundary); that doesn't explain why it's not printing anything.  Good catch on using `fist` instead of `fstp`, though.  (And on using `fild` on binary32 FP data).  But that doesn't explain why the OP's program didn't print anything, instead of printing zero (or non-zero with whatever garbage was on the stack above the 32 bits they pushed, to form the upper 32 bits of the `double` that `printf` loads .  I wouldn't recommend `DT` for `long double` unless you need it; `dq` or `dd` for double or single is fine most of the time.

Comment: @PeterCordes I would have never guessed that `dd '%lf %2X %3d', 10, 13, 0` would have encoded properly other than the 3 zeros before CR and LF.

Comment: Oh right, padding to DWORD happens for each element, at the `,` boundaries.  So `dd '%lf', 10, 0` is actually `db '%lf',0, 10,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0`.  So as a C implicit-length string, the format string is only `"%lf"`, and a line-buffered stdout won't flush before `sys_exit`.  IDK why you added a `13`; nobody uses LF CR as a newline, and Linux definitely only uses LF.  And note that the extra zeros are *after* the 10 and the 13, because x86 is little-endian.